# Нет перевода табов на странице вопросов

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, список-вопросов

[Do Not Capitalize Each Word In Tabs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323190/260198) и  [Responsive design for international sites has been released](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315979/260198).

Как понимаю, пофиксили наконец-то.

Нужно теперь перевести табы в [списке вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions).

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пофиксили так, что теперь вообще черт ногу сломит с регистрами.

Comment: @älёxölüt haha_classic.

Comment: Оформил [репорт](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323315/339911)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Featured -- Конкурсные, Frequent -- Цитируемые, Hot -- Популярные (можно было бы «Горячие», но зачем); Активно -> Текущие, Голоса -> По голосам, без принятого ответа -> Без принятого ответа, Неделя/Месяц -> За неделю/месяц.

Если есть идеи получше или видите недочеты, let's discuss.

Comment: Там ещё проблема в том, что "без принятого ответа" даже в оригинале с маленькой букве.

Comment: @Suvitruf да, я знаю, причем у нас на rus.SE всё ок, с большой буквы. Пока переписал в русской версии на заглавную.

Comment: frequent - это посты, на которые часто ссылаются в других вопросах. Так что, скорее, перевод ближе к "наиболее ссылаемые", если так по-русски вообще говорят.

Comment: @Suvitruf с наибольшим индексом цитируемости/цитирования ) м. б., цитируемые? грамматически это было бы точнее.

Comment: Да, "цитируемые", как по мне, хорошо подходит.

Comment: На вкладке вопросов такой расклад вполне понятен. Можно текст со вкладки добавить к слову «вопросы» и становится вообще полноценная фраза. Но в таком случае хотелось бы всё это согласовать со страницей «Метки» и «Участники».

Comment: @älёxölüt у меня пока нет возможности поработать над этим, так что, если вы возьмете это на себя, буду благодарен.